# Instalar php8.1 manjaro

Tags: linux, manjaro

Estoy tratando de instalar php8.1 en manjaro, pero no puedo lograrlo.

Recorrí muchos post por Internet pero todos dan el mismo comando:

```
sudo pacman -S apache php php-fpm php-gd
```

eso instala por defecto php 8.2. actualmente tengo:

```
PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2023 18:47:24) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Si alguien tiene otro método para poder instalar php8.1 se lo agradecería.

Gracias.